# How can I convert a 16-bit floatingpoint to a binary number?

Tags: floating-point, precision

I have the two following Mini-floats:

1 11010 0100010111

0 10111 0010001100

I want to covert these into a 2K Number by Hand. 
So my Question is, can anybody give me a "hint" how i can double check my results?
Maybe a quick conversion program that I can find online?

Comment: Do yo have a C compiler, or some other language? It is pretty easy to write a simple routine that displays the value of such "float16"s.

Comment: Yes, i have a c compiler, can you help me with the code?

Comment: See my answer. I don't know if the exp has a bias, otherwis the last part must be (1 << (exp - bias)).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which language you want to use, you can do something like:

```
int sign = val >> 15;
int exp = (val >> 10) & 0x1F;
int significand = val & 0x3FF;
float value = (1 - 2*sign) * (significand / 1024.0) * (1 << exp);
// now display value.
```